# Installing Ruby on Rails: -bash: bundle: command not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, installation

Having an issue running bundle in my application, I have copied the commands and logs, and display below.

`$ cd ~/Desktop/chinook/`

`$ rake db:setup`

```
rake aborted!
Gem::LoadError: You have already activated rake 11.1.2, but your Gemfile requires rake 10.4.2. Prepending `bundle exec` to your command may solve this.
/Users/kexinwu/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:34:in `block in setup'
/Users/kexinwu/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:19:in `setup'
/Users/kexinwu/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler.rb:92:in `setup'
/Users/kexinwu/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/setup.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/kexinwu/Desktop/chinook/config/boot.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/kexinwu/Desktop/chinook/config/application.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/kexinwu/Desktop/chinook/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
LoadError: cannot load such file -- bundler/setup
/Users/kexinwu/Desktop/chinook/config/boot.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/kexinwu/Desktop/chinook/config/application.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/kexinwu/Desktop/chinook/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Then after seeing that error I ran this command:

`$ gem install rake -v 10.4.2`

```
WARNING:  You don't have /Users/kexinwu/bin in your PATH,
      gem executables will not run.
Successfully installed rake-10.4.2
Parsing documentation for rake-10.4.2
Done installing documentation for rake after 1 seconds
1 gem installed
Kexins-MacBook-Pro:chinook axiner$ rake db:setup
rake aborted!
Gem::LoadError: You have already activated rake 11.1.2, but your Gemfile requires rake 10.4.2. Prepending `bundle exec` to your command may solve this.
/Users/kexinwu/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:34:in `block in setup'
/Users/kexinwu/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:19:in `setup'
/Users/kexinwu/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler.rb:92:in `setup'
/Users/kexinwu/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/setup.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/kexinwu/Desktop/chinook/config/boot.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/kexinwu/Desktop/chinook/config/application.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/kexinwu/Desktop/chinook/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
LoadError: cannot load such file -- bundler/setup
/Users/kexinwu/Desktop/chinook/config/boot.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/kexinwu/Desktop/chinook/config/application.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/kexinwu/Desktop/chinook/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

`$ bundle exec rake db:setup`

`-bash: bundle: command not found`

How do I fix this error where I can run `rake db:setup`?

Answer (score 3):

You need to install [bundler](http://bundler.io/), then you can use the `bundle` command.

```
gem install bundler
```

Comment: Hey there, thanks for the answer. So I tried your suggestion. At first, I ran "$gem install bundler" as you suggested,  and then I ran '$rake db:setup', showed an error saying missing gem 'rspec', then I 'gem install rspec'; after rspec gem was installed, I ran '$rake db:setup', showed another error saying "rake aborted! Gem::LoadError: You have already activated rake 11.1.2, but your Gemfile requires rake 10.4.2. Prepending `bundle exec` to your command may solve this." ; at last, I ran "$bundle exec rake db:setup", showed '-bash: bundle: command not found'

Comment: So now that you have bundler, you can use `bundle exec rake db:setup`. I would also run `bundle install` first, which will install all gems specified in your `Gemfile`

Comment: @axiner Are you still having issues?

Answer (score 0):

Try this command `bundle exec`

```
bundle exec rake db:setup
```